# Checking wether textboxes are equal with list items

Tags: c#

I decided to make a list with acounts in it. With a foreach I can automatically check all acounts instead of alot of elseif's. Directly below the foreach I want to check wether what is in the textboxes is equal with the acounts, if this is the case a new Form opens up.

```
Acount a = new Acount("Admin", "123");
Acount b = new Acount("Admin2", "321");            

List<Acount> acounts = new List<Acount>();
acounts.Add(a);

foreach(Acount acount in acounts)
{
    if (txtUsername.Text == ???) 
    {
        openForm();
    }
    else
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Invalid password or username.");
     }
}
```

Here the `Acount` class:

```
class Acount
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Password{ get; set; }

    public Acount()
    {

    }

    public Acount(string name, string password)
    {
        this.Name= name;
        this.Password= password;
    }  
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your `Account` class?

Comment: It depends, are you looking for reference equality or a specific property etc?

Comment: I added my entire class @PrasadTelkikar

Comment: You are mentioning textboxes, but they are nowhere in your code, maybe that's what's missing?

Comment: @Charleh They need to be equal so like "txtUsername.Text == ...". Only I don't know how to do this.

Comment: @Rafalon I edited them in the code.

Comment: `if(txtUsername.Text == acount.Name && txtPassword.Text == acount.Password)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cleanest Way to Find a Match In a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23787/cleanest-way-to-find-a-match-in-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what your are looking for is something like this:

```
if (txtUsername.Text == acount.Name && txtPassword.Text == acount.Password)
```

So if both username and password are correct for any account, you'll end up opening the new form.

Be careful however, the way your loop is currently written, even if the user enters valid credentials for one user in your list, you'll still open the `MessageBox` on each loop except the one that's good.

I'd suggest either using `.Any` as suggested by someone else, or using a boolean value to keep track of the matching status as such:

```
bool isFound = false;

foreach (Account account in accounts)
{
    if (txtUsername.Text == account.Name && txtPassword.Text == account.Text)
    {
        isFound = true; // we found a match
        break;          // no need to keep searching, we can break
    }
}

if (isFound)
    openForm();
else
    MessageBox.Show("...");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of for loops you can just use the method [Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-5.0).
Also there is a bug in your code that it would open many forms if there are multiple matches (because the for loop is not broken after finding one).

So, here is a quick solution to the code:

```
// NOTE: REMOVE THE FOR LOOP as it's not needed anymore.
// Just use the code below instead of the loop.

if (acounts.Any(account => txtUsername.Text == account.Name && account.txtPassword == account.Password)) {
    openForm();
} else {
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid password or username.");
}
```

Also don't forget to add the following `using` statements if you haven't:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an extension for handling decision call.

```
  public static class Extensions
    {
        public static void ReactWith(this Acount acct, Action succes, Action failure)
        {
            Action actionToPerform = acct != null ? succes : failure;
            actionToPerform.Invoke();
        }
    }
```

In main file call the extension as below.

```
    private void OpenForm()
    {
       // launch form code here.
    }
    private void ErrorMesage()
    {
        // Message box code here.
    }

       List<Acount> acounts = new List<Acount>();

        var validAcct = acounts.Where(a => a.Name == "abc").FirstOrDefault();
        validAcct.ReactWith(OpenForm, ErrorMesage);
```